# how to work it out in Gimp?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Here is a very easy node setup in blender:
[image]

when I apply it to a plane it results into:
[image]

suppose if we want to bring the result for a bump map, we could take it in gimp with the subtract mode set on the wave texture we get a result such as this:
[image]

the results are quite different because of the 'fac' value in the node in blender:

[image]

how can we do fix this in gimp so that I can get an image file to use it in blender as a bump map?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how to achieve a result using Gimp as opposed to Blender.

Comment: I., too voted to close the question here because it is about GIMP instead of Blender. Upon further exploration, I'd suggest moving the question to the Computer Graphics Stack Exchange site, tagged "image processing".

Comment: sorry folks, couldn't get this to my graphics accound cuz' of less reputation but after I edited the links i was able to cut the question, so i already have posted it on graphics stack exchange, I'll try and fix this and edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

If turning the layer opacity down doesn't fix it, make sure you have **only** the top layer (in Gimp) set to *subtract*. The bottom should be *normal*.

*However*, I don't think that's your problem. I think you are just using the musgrave and wave from Gimp, which has a different *seed* value (and maybe a different algorithm). Plug the texture **directly** into an *emission* shader set to strength of 1, and render that. Then do so for the other texture. Be sure to **save** both rendered images!
Now load them into Gimp as layers.

I hope this helps. Because I don't have the files, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: actually those were the rendered images in gimp that i loaded with a sample value of 10.

Comment: Okay, perhaps the image size is not the same between Gimp and Blender. Just another thought.